# Use .length > x in variable

Tags: jquery, variables

I have some plugin-generated html that goes like this (I'm entering this manually, please don't mind the mistakes:

```
<div class="pluginoutput">
<p>PersonName</p>
<p>MyData</p>
<p>Null</p>
<p>Null</p>
<p>Null</p>
</div>

<div class="pluginoutput">
<p>PersonName</p>
<p>Null</p>
<p>Null</p>
<p>Null</p>
<p>Null</p>
</div>
```

What I need is a variable counting amount of divs containing "PersonName" but only if inside the div has "Null" four times. I.e. in the above example, the variable should return 1, as only the second div has "Null" four times.

This works:

```
var m = $('div.pluginoutput:contains("PersonName")').find('p:contains("Null")').length;
```

but obviously counts all p's, i.e. returning 7 in the above example
This doesn't:

```
var n = $('div.pluginoutput:contains("PersonName")').find('p:contains("Null").length = 4').length;
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2W5KF/1/)**

```
var m = $('div.pluginoutput:contains("PersonName")').filter(function(){
    return $(this).find('p:contains("Null")').length == 4;
});
```

Comment: I added a .lengh before the last ; and it gives out what I wanted. Thank you for sharing this! I didn't know we can use fuctions while defining variables, always good to learn something new.